# Can't resize editor window in Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I'm using the Spyder Python IDE that's bundled with Anaconda 4.4.0 in Windows 10, and I'm trying to resize the editor window so that it fills the available vertical space:

[image]

I deselected *Lock panes* in the *View* menu, but I don't see any way to resize the window.  How can I vertically extend the Editor window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I closed and reopened Spyder, and somehow my windows were resized the way I wanted.  I'm not sure how that happened, but I locked my panes in this configuration, so hopefully it'll stay this way.

Answer (score 6):

Solution is:
in spyder widow go to View -> window layouts -> spyder default layout.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't click on bottom right corner and drag it down, you can go to the View menu and select maximize pane. It may become too wide but easy to narrow. Works for me anyway.